# Mysql table structure for game opponent and inviter

Tags: php, mysql, database, structure

Maybe someone can suggest solution for database table structure. I need to store to table invited user id and opponent user id and some other information. Which way to choose:
 1. do one insert by structure: id, inviter_id, opponent_id ... 
 2. do two inserts. table structure id, user_id, type (type inviter or opponent)

So thanks for answer what is better, why. Maybe will be other suggestions. :)

Comment: I'm not a MySQL expert, but this sounds like quite a broad question, what are your criteria? what is the information you need to store and when is the information you need to retrieve? What sort of Game? Is it calling data during the game whereby data updating is relatively important or is it post match data so updating speed and table locking is less important? etc. etc.

Comment: this table structure fields like: winner_user_id,points, is_mail_sent,period_id,is_mail_sent_after_game (fields are with full names to understand what are the meanings). Data will be updated when the game will finish (once a day). Mail sent field will be updated when the game finish and when the game start. Mail logic:
User will get email with information how successful he was during the game. from this table I need to get unique users to send email. If user A is who invited someone, he cann't get second  email when email will be sent to users from opponent field.

Comment: As a guide for (semi-)serious db development draw a diagram for what you want to get from the data, from which parts and what knowledge is required to do it. Also, it's hard to read the code in the comments, if you edit your question you can add it to the main question and it can be presented better :). Cheers